# Cassandra DELETEs with or without IF EXISTS

Tags: database, cassandra

I have a situation where I do not know if data exists in a set of tables. So, as of now, I am issuing DELETEs on all those tables. So, a single API call is resulting in about 30-50 DELETEs in Cassandra. Recently, it is so happening that most of the DELETEs are being issued on non-existent data. Would Cassandra's performance still be negatively affected because of the millions of DELETEs on data that does not exist? Should I use 'IF EXISTS' while deleting data that I am unsure if it exists or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to just issue regular delete without the `IF EXISTS` because in this case the coordinator starts to use serial consistency and paxos protocol which takes longer and makes other nodes run in batches etc. IF NOT EXISTS is a light weight transaction and they should be used with 1% workload, not something you do regularly.

Still you don't want to have a lot of tombstones around (what delete does) so it depends on how you model your data and how you do deletes. I'll be more than happy to provide insight on that if you give some schema, insert and delete statements ;)

Comment: so would we still have tombstones (which my initial concern was), if the data doesn't exist? nevsv says otherwise, so wanted to confirm.

Comment: if there is an "if not exists",. there would not be a tombstone ... but be careful with this one because with tombsones you are safe if you model your data o.k. ... but with if not exists you go to every node in the cluster and put significant load on the coordinator node. Use if not exists only if it's 1% of workload or less.

Comment: Just checked that DELETEs are about 55% of our requests. We are planning to revisit our schema :) Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

IF EXISTS will just fail if the row doesn't exists.

Deletes indeed affect performance, but deleting nonexistent row will do nothing (but searching for this row), it will not create tombstones for columns that aren't there.

Comment: I know that this is an old post but I want to mention here that deleting a row in Cassandra, which doesn't exists, will create a tombstone (at least in Cassandra 2.1). If you delete the same non exiting row multiple times then you will have a problem with the performance. I personally tested on Cassandra 2.1 and I confirm this 100%